# Is there a correct way of creating a bit by bit binary string?

Tags: python, struct, binary

What i come up with is using a string of 1s and 0s, concatenate it or do whatever needed, then use int(string, 2) and struct.pack. Is there other ways of handling the binary data without converting it to Python strings ?
Egg: I have a 16bits binary string, and i have to switch the stat of each one of them at will, how can I do this ?

Cheers,

Comment: Why do you have a string of 1s and 0s to begin with? Are you aware of the bitwise mathematical operators? Can you be more specific about exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have 16bits and 32bits fixed length binary data, and each bit is meant to be used for some information, I should be able to switch them at will, that is why I am not doing any computational processing !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something lightweight then you need to make your own class (there's nothing built-in). For example:

```
class BitArray(object):
    def __init__(self, array):
        """Takes a bytearray object storing the bit data"""
        self.array = array

    def setbit(self, pos, value):
        byte, bit = divmod(pos, 8)
        if value:
            self.array[byte] |= (128 >> bit)
        else:
            self.array[byte] &= ~(128 >> bit)
```

That's about as basic as it gets. You can then create your bitarray from an ordinary `bytearray`, manipulate the bits and get it back however you want.

```
a = BitArray(bytearray([0, 0])) # two zero bytes (16 zero bits)
a.setbit(3, 1) # set bit 3 to 1
print(list(a.array))
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott I'll adapt the code to my needs and add it to my modules, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a [`bitarray`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray). Going via strings is fundamentally the wrong way, even if it’s easy. It’s an example of [stringly typing](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped), which is a subversion of strong typing (and thus bad): characters are not bits. A character string is an appropriate *visual* human representation of a bit string, it should not be the *actual* machine representation, however.

Comment: Thanks @Konard, but i can't use libraries written in C or other languages, only Python, I am on a ported Linux on a ColdFire CPU !

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [bitstring](http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/) module (documentation [here](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/)), which aims to make this sort of stuff easy while still storing the data as packed bits.

You can query/set bits using standard Python notation and convert trivially to an int or to raw bytes using properties.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, but i can't use other libraries than the standard ones, since this will run on an embedded system !

Comment: @e-nouri: OK, but you also have the option of just including the single bitstring.py file as part of your system.

Comment: I will check that out, thanks for pointing that it is a single file lib, but still, I can't do this with every lib I want or need, because I am on a limited space !